# "Cannot redirect to nil!"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following along with Michael Hartl's rails tutorial and making small adjustments. Users can make microposts (status updates) on their profiles, at which point the page will appear to reload and their new status will be displayed. I can confirm by hand that this works exactly as intended. The problem is that tests for it aren't passing for some reason, even though the end result outside of tests looks perfect.

Screenshots of microposts_controller.rb, microposts_interface_test.rb (the failing test), related error messages, and users_controller.rb, in that order: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtONu.jpg

`microposts_controller.rb`

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Status updated!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @feed_items = []
      flash[:warning] = "Status was blank!"
      redirect_to @user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Status deleted."
    redirect_to @user
  end
```

`microposts_interface_test.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'

class MicropostsInterfaceTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:mrtestit)
  end

  test "micropost interface" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert is_logged_in?
    # Invalid submission
    assert_no_difference 'Micropost.count' do
      post microposts_path, micropost: { content: "" }
    end
    # Valid submission
    content = "This status really ties the room together"
    assert_difference 'Micropost.count', 1 do
      post microposts_path, micropost: { content: content }
    end
    follow_redirect!
    assert_match content, response.body
    # Delete a post.
    assert_select 'a', text: 'delete'
    first_micropost = @user.microposts.paginate(page: 1).first
    assert_difference 'Micropost.count', -1 do
      delete micropost_path(first_micropost)
    end
    # Visit a different user.
    get user_path(users(:archer))
    assert_select 'a', text: 'delete', count: 0
  end

end
```

`users_controller.rb`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if logged_in?
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
  end
```

I understand that, for some reason, this is saying that `@user` is `nil`. However, I've confirmed many times over that `redirect_to @user` works everywhere else.

The fact that every other test passes is already proof of that, but just to go the extra mile, I've confirmed that the failing `redirect_to @user` line of code works in other files, such as when a user updates their profile information under their settings page and is then redirected to their profile page. I've spent over 10 hours working on this (mostly yesterday) and am on the verge of simply deleting this test and moving on with my life. Stackoverflow is my last resort.

Comment: Please provide your code in question instead links to screenshots

Comment: I've now done what you asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you must change

```rb
redirect_to @user
```

to

```rb
redirect_to current_user
```

`@user` is class instance variable and must be created manually, eg:

```rb
@user = User.find_by_id post.owner_id
```

While `current_user` is global variable and can be used anywhere.
But don't forget check it to nil because of user can be not signed in!

You can check it manually by `unless current_user.nil?` in each method or better add helper method and use it in your controllers, tutorial already describes this way:

```rb
module SessionHelper
    def signed_in_user
        unless signed_in?
          store_location
          redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
        end
    end
# ...

class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :signed_in_user
# ...
```

**Update:**
For Aleks's advice: if you want redirect to post's owner that might be not current user, use

```rb
user = micropost.owner
redirect_to user
```

Comment: You were right! What hurts is that I got up to this point hours ago, but I wasn't sure if this was correct, so I deleted that and kept trying other things. I did that because a new error message came up, which I'm now seeing again: http://i.imgur.com/6YoYQ7J.png I'm not sure why that last part of the test is failing either. It probably has something to do with the author writing that line as "assert_select 'a', text: text: 'delete', count: 0 }", but that won't work, so I erased the second "text: " and the closed brace. A syntax error message disappears when you do that, but the code fails.

Comment: Looks like test user has access to other users. Is he admin? Try restrict access to non-admin users. View will be looks something like `<% if !current_user.nil? and current_user.admin? User.all.each do |user| %> <%= link_to user.email, user %>`

Comment: By testing several different combinations of users, I realized that line 30 is the one that's failing, not line 31. Instead of visiting a different user, the test is making the user remain on their own page, so they'll always see the number of microposts they have under microposts.yml, and there will be a matching number of delete links since they're the user who made those microposts. I tried fixing this by adding follow_redirect! to the line below it, but that didn't work since "get"ing a user path doesn't count as a redirect. Do you have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you here. I believe that creating new question for new problem will be better, may be somebody else who more familiar with tests will help you.

Comment: Good idea. Thank you!

Comment: The answer is miss-leading a visitor of SO where the user could think it should change the `SessionHelper` or tap into any of those things, where only the first line is partially correct, as it might need only setting the `@user` variable which may or may not be the current-user depending on the needs of the user.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions for this.

**First one is this:**

Change this:

```
  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Status updated!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @feed_items = []
      flash[:warning] = "Status was blank!"
      redirect_to @user
    end
  end
```

to this:

```
  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Status updated!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      @feed_items = []
      flash[:warning] = "Status was blank!"
      redirect_to current_user
    end
  end
```

**OR (if first doesn't work) the second approach:**

Update this line:

```
before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy
```

to:

```
before_action :correct_user,   only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Comment: You were right! What hurts is that I got up to this point hours ago, but I wasn't sure if this was correct, so I deleted that and kept trying other things. I did that because a new error message came up, which I'm now seeing again: http://i.imgur.com/6YoYQ7J.png I'm not sure why that last part of the test is failing. For reference, the first user is an admin, the second user is not, and they're both fixtures inside users.yml.

Comment: The reason is probably because when going to the `user_path` there is no delete link. First is admin and he could probably see a delete link, and the second link is just a regular user and should not see a delete link at all.

Comment: By testing several different combinations of users, I realized that line 30 is the one that's failing, not line 31. Instead of visiting a different user, the test is making the user remain on their own page, so they'll always see the number of microposts they have under microposts.yml, and there will be a matching number of delete links since they're the user who made those microposts. I tried fixing this by adding follow_redirect! to the line below it, but that didn't work since "get"ing a user path doesn't count as a redirect. Do you have an idea on how to fix this?